# Hi I was thinking about a problem and have a question:

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Hi I was thinking about a problem and have a question: we know that if $f∈C([0,1])$ for which $∫_0^1f(x)x^ndx=0$ for all $n \geq 0$ then $f=0$!
Now my question is: Do we still have the same when we take $f∈L^2([0,1])$, i.e. if $f∈L^2([0,1])$ for which $∫_0^1f(x)x^ndx=0$ for all $n \geq 0$ then $f=0$!
thanx!!

Comment: The most you can get is that $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: I think this was asked before

Comment: @masw980, why are you deleting your questions? Are you attempting to get your homework done for you online and hide the fact?

Comment: @masw980, the website is a valuable place and can be used to help with homework but (!), you need to be upfront about it and you need to cite in your homework you got help online (or otherwise ask your professor what is appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

We know that continuous functions are dense in $L^p([a,b])$ (where $-\infty<a<b<\infty$) and also that polynomials are dense in $C([a,b])$ and so we see that polynomials are dense in $L^p([a,b])$ by standard arguments. Thus we can see that your statement is effectively equivalent to asking if a function is orthogonal to everything in $L^2([a,b])$. Of course this gives that it must be $0$ almost everywhere. As Sami points out, this is not to say that the function is itself $0$ everywhere though (only up to a set of measure $0$ with respect to whatever measure you have).

Comment: I was thinking the same way!

Comment: I wanted edited my answer this way.+1

Answer (score 0):

In fact, one could take any function $f\in L^2([0,1])$ such that $\mu\{x \, | \, f(x) \neq 0\} = 0$.  Then $\int_0^1 x^n f(x)\, \text{d}\mu(x) = 0$, but $f(x) \neq 0$.

This is, of course, not a counterexample, but it does give an idea of the best possible result one could expect.  Namely, if $\int_0^1 f(x) x^n \,\text{d}x = 0$ for every $n\geq 0$, then $f = 0$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this to the Fourier basis problem, if that problem is known to you. More explicity, if $f \in L^{2}[0,1]$, then
$$
           f = 0\;\;a.e. \iff \int_{0}^{1}f(x)e^{i2\pi nx}\,dx =0,\;\; n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3\cdots \;.
$$
If $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)x^{n}\,dx=0$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$, then expand the exponentials in a power series to see that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)e^{i2\pi nx}\,dx=0$ for $n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\cdots\;$.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know it. Can you give more info thanx for the help.

Comment: $\{ e^{i2\pi nx}\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ is a complete orthonormal subset of $L^{2}[0,1]$, and this implies the result that you want. But, that's no good if you don't know this other fact. I only asked because the Fourier Series is usually covered earlier than other topics.

Comment: Nope didn't take Fourier analysis. Is there any other way? Or could you guide me.

Comment: If you know that (a) continuous functions can be uniformly approximated by polynomials on $[0,1]$, and (b) continuous functions are dense in $L^{2}[0,1]$, then that's another way.

Comment: Yes I do. Thanx.